# telerik:RadEditor ViewPaths http folder

Tags: asp.net

I want to set http://subdomain.supersonic2010.com/tut/images as ViewPaths of ImageManager in telerik:RadEditor 
IT Shows
'http://subdomain.supersonic2010.com/tut/images' is not a valid virtual path.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: 'http://get.therealstudy.com/tut/images' is not a valid virtual path.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a virtual path to the ViewPaths property, e.g. ViewPaths="~/Images"